# wgpu-rs: `thread 'main' panicked at 'Texture[1] does not exist'`

Tags: rust, wgpu-rs

I create a `wgpu::TextureView` within a `render` method as below:

```rust
let mut encoder = self.device.create_command_encoder(...);

let texture_view = self
    .surface
    .get_current_frame()?
    .output
    .texture
    .create_view(&wgpu::TextureViewDescriptor::default());

let mut render_pass = encoder.begin_render_pas(&wgpu::RenderPassDescriptor {
    color_attachments: &[wgpu::RenderPassColorAttachment { 
        view: &texture_view,
        ...
    }],
    ...
})

render_pass.set_/* pipeline, bind_group, vertex_buffer, index_buffer */(...);  
render_pass.draw_indexed(...);


self.queue.submit(std::iter::once(encoder.finish()));
```

But when I run the program, it panics:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Texture[1] does not exist', /home/doliphin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-core-0.10.0/src/hub.rs:129:32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is an issue for this](https://github.com/gfx-rs/wgpu/issues/1797).

This can be solved by forcing the `SurfaceTexture` to be dropped after the `TextureView`.

```rust
let mut encoder = self.device.create_command_encoder(...);

let surface_texture = self.surface.get_current_frame()?.output; // SurfaceTexture

{
    let texture_view = surface_texture
        .texture
        .create_view(&wgpu::TextureViewDescriptor::default()); // TextureView
    
    let mut render_pass = encoder.begin_render_pas(&wgpu::RenderPassDescriptor {
        color_attachments: &[wgpu::RenderPassColorAttachment { 
            view: &texture_view,
            ...
        }],
        ...
    })
    
    render_pass.set_/* pipeline, bind_group, vertex_buffer, index_buffer */(...);  
    render_pass.draw_indexed(...);
}
// drop(render_pass);
// drop(texture_view);


self.queue.submit(std::iter::once(encoder.finish()));
// drop(surface_texture) 
// drop(encoder)
```